# QueryContextMenu function gets different result on NET6.0 and NetFramework4.8

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, contextmenu, .net-4.8, windows-shell

My project is using WPF and NETFramework 4.8.
I need to get shell context menu with all items as in explorer.
I could get desirable result in Net6.0 but the same code brings less items while running in NETFramework4.8.

How to fix this?

[ContextMenu in Net6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2JAu.png)
[ContextMenu in NETFramework4.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGPAt.png)

Here is a code:
[Net6.0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1deYtkD7-zGOLIs9dyRvPL-rFBCR7PqoW/view?usp=sharing)
[NETFramework4.8](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wT8OPzE9xPCKfyC6Raydb72T7mhJlJI0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your .NET 4 app runs as x86. Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" in project properties.